# Spatial Loader DB2 giving error while importing shape file

Tags: db2, spatial

While I am trying to import a shapefile using db2se import_shape file utility,

```
db2se import_shape <dbname> -userId <userid> -pw <password> -fileName U:\ShapeFiles\ShapeFilesMarch2014\SubLimits\Africa_Criteria_Data\AF-CIV.shp -inputAttrColumns N(FIPS_CNTRY) -srsName WGS84_SRS_1003 -tableSchema GEXPDBA -tableName TPOLYGON_STAGING -tableAttrColumns VC_FLD_1 -createTableFlag 0 -spatialColumn POLYGON_OB -typeSchema db2gse -typeName st_multipolygon -messagesFile C:\AF-CIV.txt -client 1

GSE0206N  A SELECT statement failed.  SQLERROR = "SQL0805N  Package    "DB2GSE.GSEIEIMP 0X4141414141644459" was not found.  SQLSTATE=51002".
```

Any idea why this error happens? I tried in all forums and not able to debug it.

Comment: Looks like a botched or incomplete installation. Does the test program (described here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.spatial.topics.doc/doc/tsbp2004.html?lang=en) run successfully?

Comment: Yes it did. In fact, from another db2 client, the same statement works successfully

Comment: Is that _another db2 client_ of the same version? Do both client versions match the server version?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I used db2level to find the client version and the client version which was working was DB2 v9.7.500.702 and the one that was not working as DB2 v9.7.0.441

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used db2level to check the client version and found that the client version was the mismatch.

```
Not working client version
--------------------------
DB21085I  Instance "DB2" uses "32" bits and DB2 code release "SQL09070" with
level identifier "08010107". Informational tokens are "DB2 v9.7.0.441", "s090521", "NT3297", and Fix Pack "0".

Working Client version
----------------------
DB21085I  Instance "DB2" uses "32" bits and DB2 code release "SQL09075" with
level identifier "08060107". Informational tokens are "DB2 v9.7.500.702", "s111017", "IP23286", and Fix Pack "5".
```